# What is /dev/mem?

Tags: linux, memory, dev

Presumably it's somehow related to memory? What would

```
sudo cat /dev/urandom > /dev/mem
```

do? Trash all RAM? All non-kernel virtual memory? None of the above?

Comment: See also:
`dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/kmem bs=1 count=1 seek=$RANDOM`

Comment: Shouldn't memory protection stop access to the physical RAM for all processes except the one which has been assigned to that area of RAM? Or does sudo override that protection?

Comment: @MatthewLock, /dev/mem does it. It is a kernel driver that lets one read and write to arbitrary memory locations.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It provides access to the system's physical memory.

The [`mem(4)` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) explains more about what `/dev/mem` is.

Yes -- it could cause all sorts of problems. A reboot should fix you, but bad things can happen very easily. Be careful! :-)

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing the mem man page. Rags is correct.

"mem  is  a  character device file that is an image of the main memory of the computer.  It may be used, for example, to examine (and even patch) the system.

Byte addresses in mem are interpreted as physical memory addresses."

And...

"The file kmem is the same as mem, except that the kernel virtual memory rather than physical memory is accessed."

Comment: @Andrew Flanagan: Your link now shows how one may set up a stopwatch using the time command.

Comment: @Aiyion.Prime.  Thanks -- pointed to an archive.org version.

Answer (score 21):

/dev/mem provides access to the system's **physical** memory, not the virtual memory. The kernels virtual address space can be accessed using /dev/kmem.

It's primarily used to access IO memory addresses related to peripheral hardware, like video adapters.

Answer (score 18):

`sudo cat /dev/urandom > /dev/mem` won't do anything, since sudo will elevate the privilege of cat but not of the redirect. You can either do `sudo su` and then work in the root shell, or use 
`sudo dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/mem`

`/dev/mem` provides access to physical memory, i.e. all of the RAM in the system, however this doesn't mean that it gives you full read/write access to RAM (see CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM option in [this](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) document). Also note that some regions of physical memory will have other devices like video card memory, etc. mapped onto it.

Writing blindly to `/dev/mem` will result in an uncertain behaviour, [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GIu2vaIet6U) is a youtube video doing the same.

Answer (score 8):

**Test it out with `busybox devmem`**

`busybox devmem` is a tiny CLI utility that mmaps `/dev/mem`.

You can get it in Ubuntu with: `sudo apt-get install busybox`

Usage: read 4 bytes from the physical address `0x12345678`:

```
sudo busybox devmem 0x12345678
```

Write `0x9abcdef0` to that address:

```
sudo busybox devmem 0x12345678 w 0x9abcdef0
```

Source: https://github.com/mirror/busybox/blob/1_27_2/miscutils/devmem.c#L85

**`MAP_SHARED`**

When mmapping `/dev/mem`, you likely want to use:

```
open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
mmap(..., PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, ...)
```

`MAP_SHARED` makes writes go to physical memory immediately, which makes it easier to observe, and makes more sense for hardware register writes.

**`CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` and `nopat`**

To use `/dev/mem` to view and modify regular RAM on kernel v4.9, you must fist:

- disable `CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM` (set by default on Ubuntu 17.04)
- pass the `nopat` kernel command line option for x86

IO ports still work without those.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134990/mmap-of-dev-mem-fails-with-invalid-argument-for-virt-to-phys-address-but-addre/45127582#45127582

**Cache flushing**

If you try to write to RAM instead of a register, the memory may be cached by the CPU: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701352/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-for-a-region-of-address-space-in-linux and I don't see a very portable / easy way to flush it or mark the region as uncacheable:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22701352/how-to-flush-the-cpu-cache-for-a-region-of-address-space-in-linux
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885658/is-it-possible-to-allocate-in-user-space-a-non-cacheable-block-of-memory-on-li

So maybe `/dev/mem` can't be used reliably to pass memory buffers to devices?

This can't be observed in QEMU unfortunately, since QEMU does not simulates caches.

**How to test it out**

Now for the fun part. Here are a few cool setups:

- [Userland memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021214/how-to-decode-proc-pid-pagemap-entries-in-linux/45126141#45126141)

  - allocate `volatile` variable on an userland process
  - get the physical address with `/proc/<pid>/maps` + `/proc/<pid>/pagemap`
  - the physical address with `devmem2`, and watch the userland process react:
- [Kernelland memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39134990/mmap-of-dev-mem-fails-with-invalid-argument-for-virt-to-phys-address-but-addre/45127582#45127582)

  - allocate kernel memory with `kmalloc`
  - get the physical address with `virt_to_phys` and pass it back to userland
  - modify the physical address with `devmem2`
  - query the value from the kernel module
- [IO mem and QEMU virtual platform device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315265/how-to-add-a-new-device-in-qemu-source-code/44612957#44612957)

  - create a platform device with known physical register addresses
  - use `devmem2` to write to the register
  - watch `printf`s come out of the virtual device in response

Answer (score 6):

/dev/mem traditionally provided access to the entire physical address space. That includes ram but it also includes any memory mapped IO devices.

Many modern kernels will be configured with "CONFIG_STRICT_DEVMEM" which restricts /dev/mem to memory mapped IO devices only.

Writing random garbage to it is a bad idea but exactly what badness will happen is diifcult to predict. Hardware may respond in unpredictable ways to random garbage, corrupted kernel memory structures may cause unpredictable kernel behaviour. At best I would expect a system crash, at worst data corruption or even hardware bricking are not out of the question.

P.S. note that your command when run as a normal user shouldn't do anything, because the sudo only elavates the cat command, not the redirect.

Answer (score 0):

/dev/mem provides access to system's physical memory. The byte addresses in /dev/mem are interpreted as physical addresses.

/dev/kmem is similar to /dev/mem but it does not give access to any physical memory but we can access the kernel's virtual address space.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and  a [help].